# Active merchant and Paypal API for recurring payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant, paypal-subscriptions

I have few questions on paypal's recurring payments, I went trough the paypal documentation to find some answers but, it didn't help me much.

Here are the stuffs that I need to know, hope someone can help me on these.

I'm using paypal's standard payment account. So far I managed to create recurring payments with paypal by posting NVP's to paypal from merchant website to paypal.

Now I need to show recurring payment profiles on merchant web site. So that customers can cancel, modify recurring payments from merchant website without redirecting to paypal.Is this possible?

Think I should use paypal's SOAP API for this as I can't get the job done with NVP API. So I installed active merchant as described in this [post](http://intridea.com/2009/2/23/paypal-recurring-billing-with-activemerchant-in-ruby-on-rails?blog=company). But I always get an error

> This transaction is invalid. Please
>   return to the recipient's website to
>   complete your transaction using their
>   regular checkout flow.

from paypal and it never send me the token back.

Also I got this on my log

> Security header is not
>   valid

Is it because I use sandbox API credentials or is it because I can't use paypal's standard account with SOAP API?

Comment: Here is the response from paypal.

`#<ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressResponse:0x7f6c29138d40 @authorization=nil, @params={"message"=>"Security header is not valid", "timestamp"=>"2010-07-20T08:31:26Z", "correlation_id"=>"d0316c3eccb1d", "token"=>nil, "build"=>"1399980", "error_codes"=>"10002", "version"=>"59.0", "ack"=>"Failure"}, @message="Security header is not valid", @success=false, @cvv_result={"message"=>nil, "code"=>nil}, @fraud_review=false, @avs_result={"message"=>nil, "code"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil}, @test=false>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the "security header is not valid" response comes from using sandbox credentials in the live environment or vice-versa.  AM will use the sandbox when your Rails app is in development mode, so be sure you are using the right set of credentials.

When I was integrating PayPal's recurring payment profiles into the [SaaS Rails Kit](http://railskits.com/saas) (using ActiveMerchant) I ended up just canceling a user's current profile and creating a new one when they wanted to change their subscription.

Comment: I'm using the fork (http://github.com/rayvinly/active_merchant/) in my app, I tried with a "Seller" account as well as a "Website Payments Pro" account on sandbox. But none of them works for me. And the other thing is, always it redirects to LIVE PAYPAL on this code . http://bit.ly/9NP7dC

Here is the method:

setup_response = gateway.setup_agreement(:description => "EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION",
      :return_url => url_for(:action => 'confirm', :only_path => false),
      :cancel_return_url => url_for(:action => 'index', :only_path => false), :no_shipping => 1)